# Create button in "Add Connection" dialog is not working (VS 2008)

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce

I'm running Windows 7 x86, and VS2008

1) In "Server View" panel, right click to open menu and select "Add Connection...".
Dialog appears.

When I click on the Create button (left of the Browse button), dialog just closes and nothing happens.
It should open new dialog where I can create new database.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5

While installing VS2008 i selected only C# and Obfuscator. Later I tried to add SQL Server 2005 Express to see if it helps, but it didn't.

Does anyone know where can be the problem?

I also tried to look at the code Microsoft provided http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection
but Create button click event is not handled there.

2) I tried to use existing database (sample database Northwind.sdf), but after I successfully tested the connection to database, clicked OK and I had my database in project.
But any table creation or table fetch operation fails with "Failed to retrieve data for this request" error message. I'm really desperate here.

3) Don't know if this can be the case, but before VS2008 install i uninstalled VS2005 and VS2008 Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your Windows Event log for any errors.
2. If there is any service for SQL compact(not sure), then start it.
3. Try installing SP1 for VS 2008 and see if that helps.

PS: If you install SQL 2005 and want to create a database in it, select "Microsoft SQL Server" in the Add Connections dialog and not "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5".

Comment: 1) Event log didn't contain any error message. 
2) No service for SQL comapct 
3) I repaired VS2008 installation and installed SP1 - worked

PS: To repair I used different installation than first time, maybe that was also the reason why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

See this reply on MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/31ddcfa8-c566-49c7-ad19-74b1a651e1af/